# catch mouse press event on Notebook without touching tabs and their contents

Tags: events, mouseevent, children, gtkd, mousepress

I'm programming in *gtkD* on *Funtoo Linux*.
I want to catch mouse press event in *Notebook*,
but I would like to don't touch the tabs and their contents.
I'm using function: *addOnButtonPress ()* in *Notebook*,
but after that the tabs aren't reorderable ( **previously yes** ).
Or similarly, how to catch mouse events only on the selected window / widget without touching it's children.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question on: http://forum.dlang.org and I Mike Wey answered my question.
Solution:

> I see what you mean, using the enterNotify and leaveNotify events you can track if the mouse is over an tab and skip the mousePress event. The tab label do need to be wrapped in an EventBox for this to work.

SOLVED